# Cannot modify the value of a node in a onclick called function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I set the arguments of my function called on `onclick` event with PHP and I also pass "this" ( the button ) as an argument so that in my function I access the closest `<td>` node and change its value.
However, I can't change the value of the node.
I get

> is not a function

error each time I try to modify it.

PHP code :

```
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<button onclick='updateValue($index,$byte,this)'></button>";
echo "<td>".$byte."</td>";
echo "<td>".$comment."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

And my JS function there :

```
function updateValue(index,byte,button){
     $.ajax({
       url : 'commentrefresh.php',
       type : 'GET',
       data : 'bytenumber=' + byte +"&byte_id=" +index,
       datatype : 'text',

       success : function(data){
           button.closest('tr').lastChild.val(data)
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code including the HTML.

Comment: `$(button)` should work

Comment: Nop, i got the verry same result

Comment: the function recive `index, byte` but you dont use them inside function... so... you are using `val(data)` and data is not setted...

Comment: And if you share all you code, maybe we can help you.

Comment: Yeah this is just a sample to not having thousand of things to explain

Comment: well, check why the function use only data (who is not setted) first...

Comment: her is some more code but it has nothing to do with data , data is correctly set, the problem is that i cannot set the vallue of the node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddler and the way I get the lastChild td node.
https://jsfiddle.net/aqmtjs8k/

```
$(button).closest('tr').find('td:last-child')
```

And if you want to write inside the last `td` you should use `.html()` and not `.val()`

> `.val()` is only for `inputs`

#### Correct way:

`$(button).closest('tr').find('td:last-child').html(data)`

Comment: I did tried $(button).closest('tr').lastChild.html(data) but this wasn't working neither. Why does it work with what you proposed but not with what i've tried ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `closest` isn't a function on DOM nodes.

You've tagged this question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), and jQuery objects **do** have a `closest` method, but you haven't wrapped the DOM node in a jQuery object.

Comment: Well actually i've tried tones of things so i lost my mind but i did try to wrap the DOm node in a jQuery object and it get worse i cannot even acces the .lastchild but using the code i posted i can acces the lastnode i want but not modify it